# "Das ist kein Thema" - What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, expression

Recently I moved to the Konstanz area, and what I noticed is people saying "Das ist kein Thema" for everything.

So, what exactly does it mean? And when to use it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually, this is used in the sense of "no problem".

> "Kannst Du mich bitte heute abend vom Kino abholen?" -- "Klar, kein Thema."
>
> "Das ist aber ganz schön teuer." -- "Geld ist kein Thema."

---

It can of course be used literally, for example when someone is reprimanded for bringing up a topic they shouldn't have:

> "Gestern hatte ich scheußlichen Durchfall." -- "Das ist kein Thema für den Esstisch!"

...or when discussing a list of topics:

> "Sprecht Ihr dann auch über Umweltverschmutzung?" -- "Nein, das ist in der Konferenz kein Thema."

Comment: And is this like local thing, or do people all over Germany use it? Cause I never heard it before

Comment: @BЈовић I guess it's all over Germany.

Comment: It is possible that this has its origin in some local area but is used all over Germany. synonymously used phrases are "Kein Problem" or "Kein Ding"

Answer (score 14):

The basic meaning is "This is no topic requiring further discussion". It can be used in many contexts, such as to avert expressions of gratitude, or to acknowledge a request. Similar phrases that also cover a wide range of uses include *kein Ding* (regional) and *kein Problem*.

> Kannst du das bis morgen mittag erledigen? – Kein Thema.
>
> Vielen herzlichen Dank dafür! – Kein Thema.
>
> Tut mir leid, daß ich so spät bin. – Kein Thema.

Comment: +1 for _kein Ding_

Comment: Zur Abwehr von vermeintlich unangebrachtem oder unnötig ausuferndem Dank kenne ich auch seitens der älteren Generation *Keine Ursache*.

Comment: @guidot: True, but the phrase is limited to that use case. You couldn't use it in my first or third example.

Answer (score 3):

the meaning is: that's not an issue :)

Comment: Though short (and someone even downvoted it), this is actually the best answer so far. "Das ist kein Thema" is one in a long row of anglicisms that appear primarily in the speech of business people. It clearly started as a poor translation of "That's not an issue".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, it was *invented* in west germany in the early nineties or maybe even before that. I have never heard it in the eighties.

Don't overuse, since some people hate it, and it's not really useful anyway. It means something like *nevermind*, indicating that some issue does not need further discussion. But it can not be reliably understood as either yes or no.

Answer (score -3):

You are totally right concerning your confusion. *Kein Thema* is a buzzword; actually it is hip to use boring silly two-word sentences: *Kein Thema*, *nicht dafür*, *kein Problem*. Horrible!

Comment: It's not a buzzword at all. But it is colloquial speech.

Comment: Interesting. The question mentions "Das ist kein Thema." which is a full sentence, and you complain about the shortened form "Kein Thema." But nobody asked for an opinion if such sentences (or fragments) are good style or why someone would say it. You totally forgot to answer the actual question. -1 for that crap.

Comment: Good that the people from Northern Germany who would say something like _nicht dafür_ would use _da nicht für_. Three words, no matter!

Comment: The other answers covered the meaning already, so this one is more about style. 
Maybe *buzzword* is the wrong classification here. That would be a question of another forum. 
As „Das ist kein Thema“ if often shortened to „kein Thema“, the meaning is equivalent and if one of them is a buzzword(sequence), then both are. No matter the correct classification, „…kein Thema…“ has been overused a lot and should only be used if absolutely necessary, ie, never. It was hip with the wrong people for the wrong reasons. For the rest, it just sounds outdated and blasé.